# New carbon brushes, got a problem

Tags: tool-repair

So with my old table saw the carbon brushes had worn out. Since the manufacture had no replacement brushes I ended up finding some new ones myself that were the exact same size. Also had to get new caps since I broke one of those.

A while later once I got the stuff I installed it and went to turn it on, ready for what ever was to happen. No blade was installed, of course.

Upon starting there was a high pitch sound. Like with a brushed drill, when you lightly pull the trigger. And quickly turned into a harsh grind sound, almost exactly like the time when the brushes were going bad. There was also a bright yellow light from underneath. I turned it off within 2-3 seconds from when I started it.

Now this was the first time I have ever replaced some carbon brushes. So is this supposed to happen? The only two things I can think of is 1) The new brushes are flat at the end, so maybe it is wearing it round since there is little contact in the motor or 2) Wrong grade of carbon brush, to soft or too hard.

Update: I decided to run it and just let whatever happen. Only five seconds and tons of smoke came out. But I think it is because the carbon brushes are soft, not sure. I don't know what can be done at this point.

Comment: Did you get a chance to see if the commutator was still in good shape when you changed the brushes? (I had a dewalt router that self destructed that way...) Is there any chance you got the brushes in at the wrong angle? (Again, same router -- the brushes had a distinct up/down orientation that I got wrong the first time.)

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate It is a good thing I looked before out of curiosity. When I looked down the hole where the brush was nothing seemed out of the norm. So I would think not, if I have to I will haply take them back out. But I don't really know what to look for on a commutator. Also, I can say with confidence that the brushes are in correctly. Did your router also make yellow flashes, maybe smoke?

Comment: Yellow flashes/light means it's not making good contact and heating up the brushes to the point of combustion.

Comment: @ratchetfreak With the end of the carbon brush being flat and the commutator being round, is that causing the lack of contact? Would it stop if I tried getting them round? But do I need to run it to do that or actually take then out and do it myself?

Comment: When my commutator got busted by a brush self-destructing, it was pretty obvious: a few of the bars weren't bar-shaped anymore. (So you're probably good on that.) When I rebuilt it wrong, I did get sparking and smoke. Have you popped the new brushes out again to see how they look?

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate I plan on taking a look at the brushes and all once I get home. I figured I can then update the question with the results of the incident.